# I started a fire. Is my entire civilization doomed?

Tags: godus

I got the meteor power at about 4500 population, and thought it'd be neat to cast one on my own people to crash through some level 1 abodes and make room for bigger ones, which appear to have more people and belief generation within the same area.

Now my entire civilization is burning and there's nothing I can do to stop it.

I have several towns on vastly different elevations (with differences as much as 25 layers) and I have removed all means of foot traversal between them. But the fire just keeps spreading! It seems if a house explodes within a mile of any nearby houses, the fire will spread across any elevation. The workers make things worse too, since they get set on fire, then try to repair the house, which just sets the house on fire. Beautifying does absolutely nothing, except make them pretty and sparkly as they die.

I did not expect one single fire to spread this much. Did I really just waste ~18 hours of gameplay by casting a single spell? Is this a bug, or a feature?

Comment: From my reading, fire is very broken, often leading to crashes and immortal burning men. Beautify resolves fires, but they will just catch fire again. Submerging the fire in water is another approach, but will obviously kill people. You *will* run out of buildings and therefore belief so you are essentially done for. You could report it to godusbugs@22cans.com or https://22cans.zendesk.com/anonymous_requests/new, but that likely won't save you at this point.

Comment: If this is the doom of a civilization, please post a video of the process. It sounds hilarious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't help with the fire itself, but:

> Did I really just waste ~18 hours of gameplay by casting a single spell? Is this a bug, or a feature?

Hopefully not. Godus itself stores multiple backups of your game. Copy all the "state" files from your current save to have backups, and then start walking through them backwards by renaming them to state.bin one by one and starting godus up again.